# Scrollable table different width column

Tags: jquery, html, css, codeigniter, scrollable-table

anyone can help me ? i have a table [here is my table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pTJPo.png), i want this table become scrollable, i was searching on google but the column is `same width` [here](https://jsfiddle.net/onury/HsBan/) and here my column is `different width`.

here is my column changing sizes because it's my style

```
.scrollTable thead {
display: block;}

.scrollTable tbody {
display: block;
height: 320px;
overflow: auto;}
```

and here is my **HTML** code

```
  <table class="scrollTable" width="100%" >
         <thead>
            <tr id="notclickable">
               <th width="3%" class="table-conf header-table">Order No. </th>
               <th width="10%" class="table-conf header-table">Latest No</th>
               <th width="20%" class="table-conf header-table">Parts Name</th>
               <th width="7%" class="table-conf header-table">Qty</th>
               <th width="8%" class="table-conf header-table">Unit Price</th>
               <th width="10%" class="table-conf header-table">Amount</th>
            </tr>
          </thead>
          <tbody>
              <?php 
                   for ($i=0; $i < 15; $i++) :
               ?>                          
            <tr>
               <td class="table-conf <?= ($i % 2 == 0 ) ? "even" : "odd" ; ?>"><br>ganteng</td>
               <td class="table-conf <?= ($i % 2 == 0 ) ? "even" : "odd" ; ?>"><br>ganteng</td>
               <td class="table-conf <?= ($i % 2 == 0 ) ? "even" : "odd" ; ?>"><br>ganteng</td>
               <td class="table-conf <?= ($i % 2 == 0 ) ? "even" : "odd" ; ?>"><br>ganteng</td>
               <td class="table-conf <?= ($i % 2 == 0 ) ? "even" : "odd" ; ?>"><br>ganteng</td>
               <td class="table-conf <?= ($i % 2 == 0 ) ? "even" : "odd" ; ?>"><br>ganteng</td>
            </tr>
                <?php endfor; ?>
         <!-- //sek2 engkok lek bingung tak takok kon maneh iki takcobak plek karo ndk conto -->
         </tbody>
    </table>
```

Comment: Hi, Simulate the issue with jsfiddle or codepen

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/nmzvef80/1/ here sir

Answer (score 0):

Use `width:100%` and `table-layout:fixed;` like,

```
.scrollTable thead {
    display: block;
}
.scrollTable tbody tr {
    table-layout:fixed;
    display:table;
    width:100%;
}
.scrollTable tbody {
    display:block;
    height:50px;
    overflow:auto;
    width:100%;
}
```

[Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/nmzvef80/9/)

Comment: i think it's cuz `display:block`

Comment: Yes, its not good to treat `table` or `table-*` elements as `block` elements.

Comment: cuz, without display:block we can't make scrollable body , try look my fiddle plz https://jsfiddle.net/nmzvef80/1/

Comment: solved bro, i used class `table-responsive` from bootstrap , i used 3 tables there, table for thead, table for tbody and table for tfoot LoL and now it's working fine , thank you guys for answering my question ^_^